# Scriptaculous Shaking Effect Problem

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, scriptaculous

The scriptaculous shaking effect somehow produce some bugs for Webkit browsers, including Chrome and Safari. When shaking, the element will shift to the top left of the screen covering everything. An example code is given as below, are there any ways of solving this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js?load=effects'></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div style="z-index: 20000; position: fixed; display: block; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; background-attachment: scroll; background-color: white;" id="floating_text">
<p>This should be some floating text.</p>
<p>Some more floating text.</p>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dui ligula, tempus adipiscing posuere id, sollicitudin sed nulla. Sed neque diam, volutpat non interdum vel, pellentesque vitae lorem. Vivamus et leo risus. Fusce at nunc nulla, non ultricies elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam pulvinar mi at purus laoreet eu varius nisl laoreet. Mauris lobortis sapien diam. Maecenas arcu est, ullamcorper fringilla placerat nec, semper ut arcu. Curabitur metus nisl, ornare nec posuere at, tincidunt tempor nisi. Ut ut est risus. Curabitur elit urna, sagittis sagittis cursus quis, accumsan eget nulla. Donec odio ante, rutrum at fermentum vel, tempus gravida odio. Quisque a ante a urna vehicula posuere ac ut orci. Integer luctus sem et justo condimentum consequat. Phasellus pharetra malesuada velit, et commodo arcu imperdiet vitae. Suspendisse vitae risus orci. Maecenas massa tortor, sodales ut luctus ac, lacinia vitae sapien. Vestibulum sit amet rutrum est. Nullam magna erat, semper a volutpat id, porta sed nisl.</p>

<p>Praesent nec consectetur sapien. Integer mollis libero a odio pharetra vulputate. Donec mattis consequat arcu, vel ultricies orci imperdiet sit amet. Mauris sit amet tellus libero. Morbi ac venenatis ligula. Cras tellus neque, porttitor sit amet hendrerit nec, ornare quis tellus. Nam iaculis mi at mi bibendum at commodo justo pretium. Ut in nibh non diam hendrerit fermentum a ut odio. Curabitur lorem turpis, tincidunt et rhoncus et, pulvinar a metus. Vestibulum a quam sit amet arcu condimentum cursus vitae feugiat lectus. Sed ut lorem tellus, non sagittis enim. Curabitur lectus eros, commodo a elementum et, molestie eget est. Donec ullamcorper, arcu nec volutpat auctor, sem odio interdum tellus, nec volutpat lacus libero at nisl. Aliquam metus sapien, aliquam a rutrum ac, tincidunt at purus. Donec in erat mi. Quisque semper mauris in massa bibendum sed tincidunt augue facilisis. In tempus lacinia urna ac tristique.</p>

<p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce tristique urna sem. Etiam iaculis aliquam dui nec porta. Proin tristique diam non augue mattis tristique. Phasellus nulla erat, adipiscing sed cursus sed, pulvinar eget nisl. Maecenas blandit nibh eu nisl facilisis et semper turpis posuere. Pellentesque auctor sem in massa sollicitudin congue. Vivamus quis lacinia massa. Aliquam sodales dictum magna, eget ullamcorper eros placerat at. Quisque gravida diam sit amet nunc porta aliquam. Ut quis aliquet est. Maecenas risus tellus, euismod id porttitor at, porta id turpis. Phasellus id molestie ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean purus nibh, egestas vestibulum aliquet eget, luctus nec eros. Nulla facilisi. Quisque molestie, sem interdum posuere lacinia, nisl purus ornare lectus, id dapibus lacus dolor in ipsum. Aenean pharetra leo nulla.</p>

<p>Curabitur nisi quam, iaculis eget pellentesque vel, pretium sed massa. In viverra, tellus at sollicitudin fringilla, orci eros blandit elit, a bibendum mauris dolor ut metus. Vivamus pellentesque suscipit diam, vitae euismod mi pellentesque vitae. Nullam neque libero, vehicula ut iaculis at, tincidunt eget leo. Suspendisse vitae velit justo. Nullam vitae sem tincidunt nulla tincidunt mollis in id massa. Duis rhoncus elementum turpis quis mollis. Vivamus egestas urna in velit commodo iaculis. Aenean quis dolor eu odio porttitor rhoncus nec vel eros. Donec ut est eu nisl vehicula pulvinar et id dolor. Donec a dolor neque. Morbi tempus mattis tortor ut rutrum. Phasellus orci metus, pellentesque vel tincidunt nec, pulvinar eu ante. Duis faucibus felis et diam ullamcorper in feugiat urna dignissim. Quisque nec diam mauris, vel viverra arcu. Cras sagittis dignissim nisl in sagittis. Fusce venenatis rhoncus est, nec elementum libero dapibus eget. Donec eu velit metus. Sed sollicitudin felis a diam condimentum in suscipit neque varius. Nulla nec tortor tristique elit malesuada luctus luctus quis leo.</p>

<p>Nullam at quam dui. Ut gravida, tellus malesuada faucibus gravida, purus nulla consequat lorem, pellentesque egestas justo quam et enim. Suspendisse fringilla tellus id odio tristique varius. Cras et metus elit. Etiam interdum adipiscing mollis. Aliquam aliquet vestibulum imperdiet. In consectetur, nunc cursus sodales scelerisque, tellus eros tristique nisl, ut luctus augue dolor vel nibh. Fusce eget dui sed eros tristique varius lacinia id sapien. Nullam ac lorem ac lacus cursus ultricies id a risus. Ut eget dolor sem. Aliquam euismod consequat euismod. Duis sit amet neque et massa ullamcorper tempor.</p>

<p>Quisque rutrum, ipsum ac volutpat dictum, urna diam facilisis enim, ac vestibulum justo metus eu mi. Curabitur nunc sem, consequat a mollis non, bibendum vitae dolor. Mauris pulvinar pellentesque tellus, vel aliquet mauris vulputate vel. Morbi eu ante id nulla ultricies tincidunt. Proin porta, felis nec tincidunt iaculis, justo nibh laoreet dolor, eu sollicitudin arcu justo et odio. Sed suscipit tellus lobortis est tristique semper fermentum magna laoreet. Sed eget ante nunc, vitae varius purus. Mauris nec viverra neque. Morbi et lectus velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer sit amet lobortis magna.</p>

<p>Phasellus elementum iaculis sem in consectetur. Curabitur nec dictum enim. Nunc at pellentesque augue. Nulla sit amet sapien neque, et molestie augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin non elit ante. Mauris justo tellus, feugiat at dapibus a, placerat id felis. Nullam lobortis vehicula rutrum. Fusce tristique pharetra urna, ac scelerisque ipsum consequat eget. Morbi at ipsum in tellus luctus volutpat. Duis placerat accumsan lacus, dictum convallis elit porttitor eu.</p>

<p>Sed ac neque sit amet neque luctus rhoncus. Vestibulum sit amet commodo ante. Duis ullamcorper est id dui ullamcorper cursus. Maecenas fringilla ultricies turpis, nec pulvinar libero faucibus a. Quisque bibendum aliquam sapien, in fermentum arcu iaculis at. Mauris bibendum, metus sed rhoncus fringilla, nisl purus interdum eros, vitae malesuada felis est rhoncus magna. Phasellus elit justo, sagittis nec interdum tincidunt, mollis quis justo. Suspendisse rhoncus rutrum vestibulum. Aliquam ut nunc lectus, quis aliquam risus. Aliquam vel nulla sed odio blandit sagittis. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus ullamcorper, lectus facilisis eleifend accumsan, purus massa sollicitudin nunc, in sodales tellus dui eget est. Morbi ipsum nisi, semper sit amet vehicula sit amet, semper at mauris. Nam mollis massa sed risus scelerisque quis congue mauris tempus. Vestibulum nec urna magna, vitae ornare massa. Aenean adipiscing tempor rutrum.</p>

<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam in dolor eros, eleifend volutpat magna. Sed blandit gravida feugiat. Sed eu dolor in odio sagittis molestie eget ac orci. Phasellus tellus erat, scelerisque tincidunt lacinia sed, placerat eu sapien. Curabitur lobortis feugiat cursus. Nam eu egestas justo. Nullam dignissim enim ipsum, sed semper orci. Donec nulla dui, viverra vel viverra eu, eleifend nec justo. Sed in ultricies turpis. Maecenas ullamcorper, erat ac scelerisque mattis, augue magna laoreet mauris, nec sagittis tellus enim eget tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vestibulum urna eu magna ultricies adipiscing. Phasellus sed urna at nibh euismod vestibulum at eget dui. Nulla ullamcorper viverra tellus ut volutpat. Praesent hendrerit, purus a imperdiet tempus, turpis est suscipit felis, ut commodo diam orci ac augue. Quisque consectetur varius sapien, vel lobortis ante porttitor sit amet. Proin fermentum blandit justo, id faucibus elit feugiat ut. Nulla quam elit, tristique gravida ultrices in, imperdiet et enim.</p>

<p>Aliquam malesuada, nibh eget laoreet malesuada, lorem ligula gravida eros, a consectetur dui odio id urna. Vivamus tincidunt porttitor facilisis. Maecenas vitae lacus at lorem porttitor sodales. Duis et velit ac ipsum cursus ornare. Aliquam eu rhoncus est. Cras nec facilisis tellus. Nunc in felis odio. Nam facilisis dui eu lacus egestas sit amet malesuada dolor volutpat. In placerat dictum turpis ac vulputate. Suspendisse neque odio, elementum sagittis sollicitudin quis, eleifend ac orci. Proin suscipit molestie orci non venenatis. Sed metus mauris, laoreet id lobortis at, tempor eu erat. Mauris tempor, nisi id interdum tempor, tellus ligula pretium mi, a viverra nibh neque vitae est. Integer mattis, lorem ac congue fermentum, quam ipsum gravida erat, in egestas lorem eros ac massa. Vestibulum lobortis ante libero, vel fermentum ante. Aliquam augue ipsum, ullamcorper sit amet dictum id, commodo sit amet lacus. Vivamus elit purus, elementum a vestibulum quis, iaculis id metus. Cras facilisis orci in nulla consequat gravida. Integer blandit, felis at lacinia porta, lacus velit pretium magna, ut eleifend diam magna a justo. Donec scelerisque diam quis nisi molestie vel egestas urna condimentum. </p>
<script type="text/javascript">
Effect.Shake('floating_text');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DIV takes 100% of the screen once it is "absolutized" by the animation function. If you supply a height and width to "floating_text", it works fine.

Comment: But it still doesn't stop the div from going to the top left... I hope that it will stay at the bottom right corner.

Comment: I don't think the script had "position:fixed" in mind when they built it.